# How do I play a sound when ever the screen is touched?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a flappy bird-like game. However I'm struggling to find a way to play a pop sound when ever the screen is touched.

I want it to play the sound every time the screen is touched. I'm new to Android and Android Studio and I have very basic knowledge of Java. As you can see I'm a newbie.

I've tried making a `MediaPlayer` but I couldn't figure out how to make it play when the screen is touched.

Comment: Have you looked into the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events) once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SoundPool` combined with an `OnTouchListener`. In your `onTouch(..)` method you would simply do a `SoundPool.play(YOURAUDIOFILE, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);`

for example:

Create a folder named as raw under `your_app/res/`. Then paste your ringtone in this folder, for example `your_app/res/ringtone.mp3`. Now use the following code:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

// soundId for reuse later on
int soundId = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.ringtone, 1);

soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Be sure to release the SoundPool resources after use:

```
soundPool.release();
soundPool = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow

To detect the touch event first of all you must create a TouchWrapper Class, you can try more events, but im sure that this will help you, just replace the println with the sounds that you wish to play

```
class TouchableWrapper(context: Context) : FrameLayout(context) {
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> println("Moved")
            MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL -> println("Scrolled")
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

and when you have create it, in your Layout File, wrap the whole view in a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And finally in your class, just send this

```
var mTouchView: TouchableWrapper? = null
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val frameLayout = FrameLayout(context)
    Fonty.Companion.setFonts(container)
    populateViewForOrientation(inflater, frameLayout)
    mTouchView = TouchableWrapper(this.context!!)
    mTouchView!!.addView(frameLayout)
    return mTouchView
}
```